# Отсортировать очередь

Tags: java

У меня есть приоритетная очередь, которая сейчас сортируется таким образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно поменять метод compareTo , чтобы элементы сортировались по убыванию.
То нужно чтобы получился результат как будто я у своей очереди вызвал метод reverse

Comment: Где Вы стянули этот код?

Comment: O. Count - this. Count